# Compile Visual C++ 6 project with winegcc

Tags: c, winapi, wine

I'm trying to compile the default sample win32 ,Hello World project .
I did `winegcc -m32 -o test2 test2.cpp`  . It runs ok , but resources are not loaded ,there is empty windows title and more .What is the correct way to make it also laod the resources?
Here is again the project code:

```
    // test2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "resource.h"

    #define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

    // Global Variables:
    HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
    TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                              // The title bar text
    TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];                                // The title bar text

    // Foward declarations of functions included in this code module:
    ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
    BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
    LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
    LRESULT CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

    int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                         HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                         LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                         int       nCmdShow)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here.
        MSG msg;
        HACCEL hAccelTable;

        // Initialize global strings
        LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
        LoadString(hInstance, IDC_TEST2, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
        MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

        // Perform application initialization:
        if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow)) 
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDC_TEST2);

        // Main message loop:
        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) 
        {
            if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) 
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }

        return msg.wParam;
    }



    //
    //  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
    //
    //  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
    //
    //  COMMENTS:
    //
    //    This function and its usage is only necessary if you want this code
    //    to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'
    //    function that was added to Windows 95. It is important to call this function
    //    so that the application will get 'well formed' small icons associated
    //    with it.
    //
    ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
    {
        WNDCLASSEX wcex;

        wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX); 

        wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wcex.lpfnWndProc    = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
        wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
        wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
        wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
        wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDI_TEST2);
        wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
        wcex.lpszMenuName   = (LPCSTR)IDC_TEST2;
        wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
        wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDI_SMALL);

        return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
    }

    //
    //   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HANDLE, int)
    //
    //   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
    //
    //   COMMENTS:
    //
    //        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
    //        create and display the main program window.
    //
    BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
    {
       HWND hWnd;

       hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

       hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
          CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

       if (!hWnd)
       {
          return FALSE;
       }

       ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
       UpdateWindow(hWnd);

       return TRUE;
    }

    //
    //  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, unsigned, WORD, LONG)
    //
    //  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
    //
    //  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
    //  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
    //  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
    //
    //
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        int wmId, wmEvent;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc;
        TCHAR szHello[MAX_LOADSTRING];
        LoadString(hInst, IDS_HELLO, szHello, MAX_LOADSTRING);

        switch (message) 
        {
            case WM_COMMAND:
                wmId    = LOWORD(wParam); 
                wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam); 
                // Parse the menu selections:
                switch (wmId)
                {
                    case IDM_ABOUT:
                       DialogBox(hInst, (LPCTSTR)IDD_ABOUTBOX, hWnd, (DLGPROC)About);
                       break;
                    case IDM_EXIT:
                       DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                       break;
                    default:
                       return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
                }
                break;
            case WM_PAINT:
                hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
                // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
                RECT rt;
                GetClientRect(hWnd, &rt);
                DrawText(hdc, szHello, strlen(szHello), &rt, DT_CENTER);
                EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
                break;
            case WM_DESTROY:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
       }
       return 0;
    }

    // Mesage handler for about box.
    LRESULT CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {H
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
                return TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL) 
            {
                EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
                return TRUE;
            }
            break;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winegcc is able to process one file. To convert complex project use [Winemaker](https://dl.winehq.org/wine/docs/en/winelib-guide.html#WINEMAKER-INTRODUCTION). It generates UNIX makefiles.

Run the following command near your project file:

```
winemaker --lower-uppercase --nomfc
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to run it this way ,inspired from winemaker :

```
wineg++ -c   -I.    -o test2.o test2.cpp

wrc   -I.    -fotest2.res test2.rc

wineg++ -m32 -mwindows -mno-cygwin -o test2.exe  test2.o test2.res -lodbc32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lwinspool -lodbccp32
```

Comment: Winlib provides more convenient way to do it. Please check my answer.